# Java multiple inheritance duplicate variable declaration?

Tags: java, inheritance

I was testing the capabilities and abuse of the default keyword in Java. I decided to test multiple inheritance and what would happen if I declared two variables of the same name and signature in an interface and in the class implementing the interface.

Code:
http://ideone.com/mKJjst

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

interface Foo {
    default void Meh() {
        System.out.println("Foo.Meh");
    }
}

interface Bar {
    String test="t";

    default String getTest(){
        return test;
    }

    default void doTest(){
        System.out.println("Bar.doTest: -- getTest" + getTest());
    }

    default void Bar() {
        System.out.println("Bar.Bar()");
        String blahh=test;

    }
    static void Sup(){
        System.out.println("Bar.Sup -- Test: "+test);
    }
    default void Meh() {
        System.out.println("Bar.Meh -- Test: "+test);
    }

    default void mega() {
        Meh();
    }
}

abstract class Test {
    public void Meh() {
        System.out.println("Test.Meh");
    }
}

class Ideone extends Test implements Foo, Bar {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        new Ideone().Meh();
        blah();
    }

    public void Meh() {
        Bar.super.Bar();
        Bar.super.Meh();
        System.out.println("Ideone.Meh -- Test: "+test);

        Foo.super.Meh();
        super.Meh();


        Bar hack = new Bar(){

             public static final String test="over";

             public String getTest(){
                System.out.println("Ideone.Meh.hack.super.test: " + Bar.super.getTest());
                return test;
             }

             public void Meh(){
                System.out.println("Ideone.Meh.hack.Meh()");

                func();
                Bar.Sup();
                Bar.super.Meh();
             }

             public void func(){
                System.out.println("Ideone.Meh.hack.func -- Test: "+test);
             }
        };

        hack.Meh();
        System.out.println("Ideone.Meh.hack.test: " + hack.test);
        hack.mega();
        hack.doTest();
    }

    public static void blah() {

    }
}
```

Results:

```
Bar.Bar()
Bar.Meh -- Test: t
Ideone.Meh -- Test: t
Foo.Meh
Test.Meh
Ideone.Meh.hack.Meh()
Ideone.Meh.hack.func -- Test: over
Bar.Sup -- Test: t
Bar.Meh -- Test: t
Ideone.Meh.hack.test: t
Ideone.Meh.hack.Meh()
Ideone.Meh.hack.func -- Test: over
Bar.Sup -- Test: t
Bar.Meh -- Test: t
Ideone.Meh.hack.super.test: t
Bar.doTest: -- getTestover
```

How is it possible that `Bar hack` can have a variable called `test` with a value of `over` and at the same time have a variable called `test` with a value of `t`?

Also, is `Bar hack = new Bar();` inheriting from itself? If hack is an instance of `Bar`, how can it have a `super` that is of type `Bar` and contains a different `test`?

What's actually going on here?

Comment: Hint: See what happens if, in your `Meh` method, you try to assign a value to `Foo.this.t`.

Comment: You can't.. it's static final? Both are static final.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How is it possible that `Bar hack` can have a variable called `test` with a value of `over` and at the same time have a variable called `test` with a value of `t`?

Interfaces can only declare constants (`static final` is implicit). Therefore the object `Bar hack` doesn't have any [instance] variables, it just has scope access to two static final variables that happen to have the same name, declared by an interface and a class respectively.

> Also, is `Bar hack = new Bar();` inheriting from itself? If hack is an instance of `Bar`, how can it have a `super` that is of type `Bar` and contains a different `test`?

Actually, `Bar hack = new Bar() { ... };`. So `hack` is in instance of an anonymous inner subclass of `Bar`. Yes, this one-off subclass does inherit from class `Bar`.

> What's actually going on here?

You're learning Java :)

Answer (score 1):

1.

```
How is it possible that Bar hack can have a variable called test with a value of over and at the same time have a variable called test with a value of t?
```

This statement is false. In java there are classes and instances of classes. A static constant/variable belongs to the class not to the instances of that class. So

```
Bar hack = new Bar() {

         public static final String test="over";
```

Above `test` constant belongs to Bar annonymous class (Bar$1.class) not Bar.class. `test` constant with value `"t"` is what belongs to Bar.class. So using it within `func` method the will print the closest scoped variable which is obviously has the value `"over"`

```
public void func(){
         System.out.println("Ideone.Meh.hack.func -- Test: "+test);
}
```

So if you want to print `Bar.test` since test is a public static constant that belongs to Bar you can use the follow code.

```
public void func(){
         System.out.println("Ideone.Meh.hack.func -- Test: "+Bar.test);
}
```

2.

```
Also, is Bar hack = new Bar(); inheriting from itself? If hack is an instance of Bar, how can it have a super that is of type Bar and contains a different test?
```

As I said earlier following declaration results in an annonymous inner class which implements Bar.

```
         Bar hack = new Bar(){

             public static final String test="over";

             public String getTest(){
                System.out.println("Ideone.Meh.hack.super.test: " + Bar.super.getTest());
                return test;
             }

             public void Meh(){
                System.out.println("Ideone.Meh.hack.Meh()");

                func();
                Bar.Sup();
                Bar.super.Meh();
             }

             public void func(){
                System.out.println("Ideone.Meh.hack.func -- Test: "+test);
             }
        };
```

True hack is a Bar but test is a static constant which means it doesn't belong to the class instance but to the class.